# Visual Studio Code IDE returns error when attempt to debug React Native project: Could not find device with the id: "simulator"

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code

### My environment.

- Windows 10 with Android SDK and AVD Manager and VS Code 1.26.1
- Android Nexus S simulator with SDK API 23 Android 6.0 x86_64
- react-native: 0.55.4

### Problem:

I am failing to debug my sample app.js in Visual Studio Code IDE and fail to stop at any breakpoint.

I have AVD emulator running and when I simply run my simple project, the simulator loads it without issues. So, I do not see a problem with my project.
I also can execute “react-native run-android” in Terminal window of VS Code IDE and it returns success, for example:

> BUILD SUCCESSFUL Total time: 10.283 secs Running
>   C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s
>   emulator-5554 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 Starting the app on
>   emulator-5554
>   (C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s
>   emulator-5554 shell am start -n
>   com.vscodereactdebug3/com.vscodereactdebug3.MainActivity)... Starting:
>   Intent { cmp=com.vscodereactdebug3/.MainActivity }

However, when I attempt to debug it through Visual Studio IDE (Debug/Start Debugging), the Debug Console shows the following:

> *OS: win32 x64 Adapter node: v8.9.3 x64 vscode-chrome-debug-core: 3.17.3 Could not debug. Unknown error: not all success patterns were matched. It means that "react-native run-android" command failed.
>   Please, check the View -> Toggle Output -> React Native, View ->
>   Toggle Output -> React Native: Run android output windows.*

So, below is output from **React Native: Run Android**:

> *[Warning] Target simulator is not supported for Android platform. If you want to use particular device or simulator for launching Android
>   app, please specify  device id (as in 'adb devices' output)
>   instead.
>
>  [Info] local.properties file doesn't exist. Using
>   Android SDK location from PATH. [Info] Starting React Native
>   Packager.
>
>  [Info] Attaching to running React Native
>   packager
>
>  Scanning folders for symlinks in
>   e:\Software\Android\VSCodeReactDebug3\node_modules (20ms) Could not
>   find device with the id: "simulator".
>  Choose one of the
>   following:
>  [ 'emulator-5554' ]*

I searched forums for the greater wisdom and saw a few posts related to this erratic behavior but those, while sharing good troubleshooting clues, did not solve my problem:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-react-native/issues/624

My project is very simple, almost empty few liners.  So, very likely the problem is with my environment, but I cannot find anything that could explain it.  I do not recall assigning ID “simulator” to anything.  And do not know where it is controlled.

Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Update.**

Today I came across of post [React Native debug with Visual Studio Code not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490966/react-native-debug-with-visual-studio-code-not-working)
and attempted uninstalling react-native package and installing react-native-cli.  I literally ran following commands in that sequence to use create-react-native-app:

```
npm install react-native --global
npm uninstall -g react-native
npm install -g react-native-cli
```

So, now the IDE debugs and stops on breakpoints as before.

I am yet to learn what happened and why my other project suddenly stopped being debugged. I, perhaps, broke my environment attempting to recover from some other problem.
And I still cannot explain the error related to "Could not find device with the id: "simulator"" in the Debug output.